# Background Video with a Play Button, on button click play another video over background video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transferwise

I can create background video with this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fullscreen_video

But I want to make this like on this [TransferWise](https://transferwise.com/) site.

Video will be **played in background** but when I click the **play** button **another video** should be played.

Comment: It's really hard to know if the TransferWise site is still the same.  It's been rebranded to Wise.  It would be better in the future to send a screenshot or a screen recording in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/player_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var tv,
  playerDefaults = {autoplay: 0, autohide: 1, modestbranding: 0, rel: 0, showinfo: 0, controls: 0, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 0, iv_load_policy: 3};
var vid = [
   {'videoId': '2b5QNj-BVhs', 'startSeconds': 515, 'endSeconds': 690, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
   {'videoId': '9ge5PzHSS0Y', 'startSeconds': 465, 'endSeconds': 657, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
   {'videoId': 'OWsCt7B-KWs', 'startSeconds': 0, 'endSeconds': 240, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
   {'videoId': 'qMR-mPlyduE', 'startSeconds': 19, 'endSeconds': 241, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'}
  ],
  randomVid = Math.floor(Math.random() * vid.length),
    currVid = randomVid;

$('.hi em:last-of-type').html(vid.length);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){
  tv = new YT.Player('tv', {events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
}

function onPlayerReady(){
  tv.loadVideoById(vid[currVid]);
  tv.mute();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  if (e.data === 1){
    $('#tv').addClass('active');
    $('.hi em:nth-of-type(2)').html(currVid + 1);
  } else if (e.data === 2){
    $('#tv').removeClass('active');
    if(currVid === vid.length - 1){
      currVid = 0;
    } else {
      currVid++;  
    }
    tv.loadVideoById(vid[currVid]);
    tv.seekTo(vid[currVid].startSeconds);
  }
}

function vidRescale(){

  var w = $(window).width()+200,
    h = $(window).height()+200;

  if (w/h > 16/9){
    tv.setSize(w, w/16*9);
    $('.tv .screen').css({'left': '0px'});
  } else {
    tv.setSize(h/9*16, h);
    $('.tv .screen').css({'left': -($('.tv .screen').outerWidth()-w)/2});
  }
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  vidRescale();
});

$('.hi span:first-of-type').on('click', function(){
  $('#tv').toggleClass('mute');
  $('.hi em:first-of-type').toggleClass('hidden');
  if($('#tv').hasClass('mute')){
    tv.mute();
  } else {
    tv.unMute();
  }
});

$('.hi span:last-of-type').on('click', function(){
  $('.hi em:nth-of-type(2)').html('~');
  tv.pauseVideo();
});
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto Slab Regular'), local('RobotoSlab-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v7/BngMUXZYTXPIvIBgJJSb6ufN5qA.ttf) format('truetype');
  }
  body {
    background: #000;
  }
  a {
    color: #ff0;
  }
  .cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .cover .hi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cover .hi span {
    color: #ff0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .cover .hi em {
    font-style: normal;
  }
  .cover .hi em.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .tv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .tv .screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  .tv .screen.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cover">
   <div class="hi">This is fully responsive & mobile friendly YouTube video background scaled with 16/9 aspect ratio. Actually bunch of videos - js loads randomly 1 of 4 with different start/end times, then it loops through all the vids.<br><br> Click <span>here</span> to <em>un</em>mute & <span>here</span> to see another vid (<em>0</em> of <em>0</em>). Check all of them! They're quite awesome. ;]</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tv">
    <div class="screen mute" id="tv"></div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

or below is the link of the soliution

[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RExKry][1]
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. Did you see the example I mentioned on https://transferwise.com/